# How to change usage highlight color in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Dracula theme, when I click on a symbol, even though IntelliJ IDEA highlights the usages of that symbol, the highlights are not that visible. I need to change the highlight text color and background color of usages so usages are more visible. I Googled for a solution but couldn't find.

Following page mentions that this can be done in Colors and Fonts settings page but I couldn't find where I can change the colors in that page.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/highlighting-usages.html

Can somebody help me in this please?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Go into Settings->IDE Settings->Editor->Color and Fonts->General

Make a copy of Darcula to something like MyOwnDarcula (can't change the built in schema).

Find whatever you need to change, in this case I think it's "Identifier under caret" and change the colors for foreground and background to your liking.

Comment: What's the category of the declaration of a variable under the caret?  If I select a use of variable all uses are highlighted but not the declaration.  I can't see how I can change its highlighting.  Any ideas?

Comment: @HanCa it is under `Code`

Comment: You need to change the **"Identifier under caret (write)"** as well. I picked `82D95C` as the **background** and some dark-color for **foreground** to make it more legible. Now, it looks good to me.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [Solarized](https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized)  and [Monokai](https://darekkay.com/2014/11/23/monokai-theme-intellij/) theme for IntelliJ.

Comment: @LahiruChandima damn they should have made the `i` be a longer variable name. I honestly did not see it.

Comment: Making a copy of color scheme is not required now. We can make changes to the built-in color scheme.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is wrong. Editor>Colors & Fonts>General>Selection background/Selection foreground

Comment: The question is asking for "usage highlight color". It looks your answer is for "highlight color".

Comment: The accepted answer isn't right (the path is out-of-date and the option name is wrong), but the path mentioned here is out-of-date and there's no correcting of the option name...

Answer (score 17):

It's called "identifier under caret" and "identifier under caret (write)".

I suggest editing background color.

[image]

Comment: Found this looking to change the color of the highlighting when you start a refactor (name change), then move the cursor with the keyboard? In other words, Shift+F6, Left/Right Arrow... For anyone having the same issue, it's "Search result (write access)."

Answer (score 7):

Steps for your solution are:

1. File->setting  or ctrl+alt+s
2. Got `identifier under caret`(For finding this click on `code` in general tab and enter `identifier under caret`). Refer image.

[image: ss1]

Answer (score 0):

The linked page also mentions [Highlighting usages of a symbol in the current file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/highlighting-usages.html#highlighting_usages_in_current_file) with a `Ctrl + Shift + F7` keyboard shortcut.

The highlighting for that is governed by "Search Results" > "Search Result" (under Editor > Color Scheme > General)